# Cloud and REST API based Recording and storing to Google bucket or AWS S3

Tags: agora.io

I need to do cloud based recording. I need to take all video+audio streams of all clients. Then push to AWS S3 or Gcloud bucket or Agora storage itself. I need to do it through API since I have some criteria and also I need to organize the uploaded data in specific folder names.

I did not see any specific function in agora service to do so. Should I take copy of localstream and handle it on my own? If so, I hope it does not come in the way of agora functionality.. Please share if any sample project. Just to emphasize- I am not looking for on-premise SDK. I need to do it through REST. I use angular 8. I could write my own REST server (to deal cloud of my choice) if really needed.

Background study done-
In agora.IO documentation, I see lot of documentation about on-premise recording. I did not see any reference for cloud based recording.  I checked the agora.IO documentation and also angular code which includes agora service component. Angular sample works fine. But I did not understand how to take the stream and upload to my cloud storage. I am concerned that it might impact the streaming and playback of agora. To handle this , I thought you might have specific guideline or library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new [Cloud Recording API](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/product_cloud_recording%20?platform=Linux) in beta that Agora is offering that can connect to the channel and record the streams (configured by RESTful API) directly to your S3 bucket, currently GCP is not supported.

This is an add-on feature so it's not enabled by default and not available to be enabled through the dashboard, it needs to be enabled by the Agora team. Please [Join the Agora Community Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/agoraiodev/shared_invite/enQtNjk0OTg4ODgyNTc5LTczOWQ0YjBkMTMwZDFmYzViYjIxNjg4YTM0OWEzZjdkODM1NDNmOTM1ZTE4Y2Q1ZWUwMjNjMzMxMmZiNGI3ODg) and send me a direct message with the `AppID` for which you wish to enable with this feature and I can get you into the beta program.

Comment: Can I save the video in the Google Cloud Storage now in 2020? I ask this question, becouse I see - "In fact, Google Cloud Storage (GCS) optionally offers access via an S3-compatible API."