# Can Agora.io cloud recording save to a Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: agora.io

I have been able to use the agora.io REST APIs to enable cloud recording to an AWS S3 bucket as a test using your Unity SDK. For our project, we would like to store to Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

I don't see a vendor ID for GCS in the agora documentation (even though GCS is supposed to be compatible with the AWS APIs). Is GCS supported? If so, what's the vendor ID?

I see a similar question last year at [Cloud and REST API based Recording and storing to Google bucket or AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127489/cloud-and-rest-api-based-recording-and-storing-to-google-bucket-or-aws-s3)

Answer (score 0):

#Updated Dec 2021

The Agora Cloud Recording Service does now support GCP.
As mentioned in the Cloud Recording documentation, the service supports:

0: Qiniu Cloud
1: Amazon S3
2: Alibaba Cloud
3: Tencent Cloud
4: Kingsoft Cloud
5: Microsoft Azure
6: Google Cloud
7: Huawei Cloud
8: Baidu AI Cloud

Documentation reference: https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=All%20Platforms

Comment: Updated to reflect its now working with GCP

Answer (score 0):

It is supported now[image]

Documentation reference:
https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=All%20Platforms